# Lucene.net get entire csv rows with matches

Tags: lucene.net

I need to search a term (or more terms) inside huge csv files.
I foud Lucene.Net as the best way to make a fast query on them.

Well, l'm able to create an index and make queries but I cant get the entire rows that contains the match.

I'm trying with the highlighter class, but I need to cut the string around the correct row and I think this is not the best way..

Comment: How do you index the files? Is every file in one single field in the document or one row per field? Do you need every match per file or just the first one?

Comment: Each file has a lot of rows and every row have list of values separed by TAB.
These files are huge, up to 2 gb, and I want to check the performances of lucene.
I index the entire files, I want to get the entire rows with the word that match...

Comment: So your Document has one single Field which contains one whole csv file with all rows?

Comment: At the end I moved all into a database, with the correct index is quite fast..

Answer (score 0):

You should put each row in an individual Document on indexing (say, in `"csv_row"` field), then access it via `doc.Get("csv_row")` in search result documents.

P.S. Lucene is really the right way to search within huge text files, much faster than the database.